# Capitalize only the first letter of a name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table *Vendors* that contains a column *VendorContactFname*, which
is written in lowercase.

I want to capitalize only its first letter. I am thinking of concatenating an Upper on the first letter to the left, with all other remaining letters to its right in their original lower case, i.e., with the substring:

```
Upper(Left(VendorContactFname,1) ) + 
Substring('VendorContactFName',2, Len('contactFname')-1 )
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to replace the first character directly:

```
-- Demo
SELECT
    STUFF
    (
        O.name,
        1, 1,
        UPPER(LEFT(O.name, 1))
    )
FROM sys.objects AS O;
```